# List with generics is not being identified by RAD6

Tags: java, rad

I am using RAD6. I wrote the following code.

```
private List<C1> list;
public List<C1> getList() {
return list;
}
```

But on second line of above code compiler is giving following two errors.

1: Syntax error on token delete these tokens.

2: Return type of the method is missing.

Comment: either RAD6 doesn't support java5, or you don't have a java5 or better  jdk installed. what does `java -version` report?

Comment: It is reporting    java version "1.6.0_06"

Comment: I don't believe that RAD6 supports Java 6 (or even 5 for that matter) out of the box. It may be possible to add the support but I doubt that would be very simple. Even RAD7 only supports Java5 and not 6. Is there any specific reason you have to use RAD6, since it is quite an old version (that wasn't very good even at the time of release and was very quickly superseded by RAD7 anyway). In any case, you can check in the Preferences screen what versions are available under Compiler/Compliance.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC RAD6 doesn't support JDK 1.5 syntax, being based on Eclipse 3.0. [(See this thread)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=13789355)

If they released a RAD6 with 1.5+ support, the project itself *also* needs to be configured for JDK 1.5, otherwise it will assume only JDK 1.4 syntax is allowed.